# Sed for windows not working after Powershell edit

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell, sed

I want to automate selecting data out of a pdf file for later processing in a spreadsheet.
1: Copy all text into a .txt file, using Notepad  - ok. 2: Remove all newlines, CRLF, to create a single line file,using Powershell - ok

3: Sed edits to cut out unwanted text don't work (I have successfully used sed for 2 years).

powershell -command ""$(Get-Content T1.txt)" > t2.txt"

sed -i -r "s/Limited/XX/g" t2.txt - does not work.

Yet removing all newlines manually using Notepad++ (using regex \r\n) to create the txt file, the same sed command works ok. Any ideas? Maybe alternative to removing all newlines in a .bat file?
Using Win7 Prof 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is a POSIX tool designed to handle text. Possibly your "single line file" is not a [text file in terms of POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403):

> A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines. The lines do not contain NUL characters and none can exceed `{LINE_MAX}` bytes in length, including the <newline> character. […] many utilities only produce predictable or meaningful output when operating on text files.

Unless empty, it will contain an [incomplete line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195) only:

> A sequence of one or more non-<newline> characters at the end of the file.

Compare to the definition of [line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206):

> A sequence of zero or more non-<newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character.

`LF` is the <newline> character (`CR` is not; in this context `CR` is not special).

I don't know Powershell and I cannot tell if your code is sane, but if it removes all newlines then it probably creates an incomplete line. I guess Notepad++ is smart enough to complete the line anyway.

Some implementations of `sed` don't process incomplete lines ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2373108/10765659)) and some do (at least GNU `sed` does). Apparently your `sed` doesn't. Find `sed` that does or make sure the "single line" is properly terminated by a <newline> character. E.g. in Unix this command:

```
echo >> T1.txt
```

appends exactly one <newline> character to `T1.txt`. I don't know a Powershell way, sorry.

Note if the fixed `T1.txt` exceeded `{LINE_MAX}` bytes in its single line, then formally it would still not be a text file, so text processing utilities might still not work with it. My point is your `sed` may have a line length limit and therefore it may not work in some cases, even after you fix the file by adding a terminating <newline> character.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218737/108618) to get an idea for workaround.